# The term 'csc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, etc. (New to C#. Learning from 'C#8.0 and .NET Core 3.0)

Tags: c#, new-operator, csc

Very new to programming here.  I am going through 'C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0 book'.  I tried to check which versions of the C# compiler are available, but the term 'csc' isn't recognized.  I have installed C# to Visual Studio Code and played with this a little, but I am new, so figure now is a good time to ask questions.  Any tips would be appreciated.
[image: Screenshot of terminal showing that 'csc' not ok]

Comment: Do you have a dotnet SDK installed? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60#install-alongside-visual-studio-code

Comment: That doesn't work on my system either, because normally `csc` isn't in your path. The command to build things with is `dotnet build`.

Comment: The VS installer usually includes a shortcut for a "Developer PowerShell for VS 20XX", will launch PowerShell with the correct paths to resolve `csc` (and other compiler tools)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen OP: _" I have installed C# to Visual Studio **Code**"_ (emphasis by me) I guess OP is refering to the C# Extension to VS Code.

Comment: @Fildor Cheers, I missed that part.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults)

Comment: To get installed .NET information, open a cmd window and type `dotnet --info`. The following may also be useful: [Microsoft .NET and .NET Core Lifecyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core).

Comment: Thanks everybody!  I went through each comment and have learnt a lot today.  I think the issue is that I am going through a book based on .NET Core 3.0 and am running .NET Core 6.0.  Thanks again!  This is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Locate the path of `csc.exe` and add it your `PATH` environment variable.
   Probably `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`. There will be csc.exe for all versions like v2.0.XXXXX and v3.5. Select the one with the highest version in Framework64/Framework directory depending on your requirement.
2. Copy the path of csc.exe and add it to the PATH system environment variable.
3. Quit the CMD, and then launch again and run the program

Comment: The `csc` you find this way is the C# compiler that comes with the .NET Framework. These are legacy compilers that will not compile .NET Core code (well, not correctly, at least). Even for compiling Framework code they should not be used in favor of the build system that comes with Visual Studio (Code), since these are newer (Roslyn-based), and they will issue a warning to that effect if you run them from the command line without parameters.

Comment: Thanks Danylo, Jeroen and everybody else here.  I went through each comment and answer, tried it out and have learnt a lot today!  So very much appreciated.  I still can't get it to work, but likely this is my being very new.  The book I am going through is for .NET core 3.0 and the version running is 6.0, so I am guessing that is the issue.  Jeroen, thanks for the legacy compiler comment.  Just went through that in the book.  Nice reminder.  I'm going to log off now and continue with this tomorrow.  Thanks all!

Comment: Thanks Danylo and everyone else.  It turns out I wasn't updating the PATH system environment variable correctly.  Used this handy little video to get some guidance.  So a small victory for a new guy.  (In short the solution provided, worked perfectly, I just didn't understand at first)